# Javascript - get contents of div, decode base64, replace the same div with decoded contents

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a page with a div, which might or might not (no control over contents) have base64 encoded contents. I have a button, which when clicked will get the contents of the div, decode the base64 and then replace that same div with the decoded contents.

I know that innerHTML can get contents of whichever element.
I know that `btoa()` and `atob()` can decode base64, and there are enough functions on the web to do it for IE.

I however don't know how to combine the two, and afterwards replace the contents of that same div with the decoded result. What would be the best way to do above thing? Jquery is available, other frameworks are not.

Comment: Wrong stack. This stack is for servers and faults and serverfaults (as the name suggests).

Comment: post some sample html ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the jquery [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) like this

```
<div class="encoded">SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=</div>
```

and

```
$('.encoded').html(function(i,current){
    return atob(current); //return the decoded string
});
```

Assuming that the div you want to target has a class `encoded` applied to it.. (*that class is just an example for targeting the element*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k5SSH/1//

Comment: Why can't this be written as: `$('.encoded').html(atob($('.encoded').html()));`?

Comment: @SathyeshSelvarajah, it can. But i want to avoid re-using a selector and making a second DOM query..

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use a function like this:

```
  function encode64(input) {
     input = escape(input);
     var output = "";
     var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
     var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
     var i = 0;

     do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
           enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
           enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
           keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
     } while (i < input.length);

     return output;
  }

  function decode64(input) {
     var output = "";
     var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
     var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
     var i = 0;

     // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
     var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
     if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
              "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
              "Expect errors in decoding.");
     }
     input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

     do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

     } while (i < input.length);

     return unescape(output);
  }
```

#### More Info: http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html